# Iptables: forward port from one host to another inside same bridged network

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a network like this:

```
Internet <===> Modem/Router <--------->  Switch
           1.2.3.4    192.168.1.1/24     |  |  |
                                         |  |  |
                                   +-----+  |  +------+
                                   |        |         |
                                  PC 2      |        PC 3
                          192.168.1.3/24    |       192.168.1.4/24
                                            |
                                           PC 1
                                       192.168.1.2/24
                                           /|\
                                           WLAN
                                          / | \
                                    PC W1 PC W2 PC W3 
                                     192.168.1.X/24 (X>10)
```

Modem/Router act as DHCP server too. Any request sent on public IP 1.2.3.4 is redirected to 192.168.1.2 on internal network. Modem/Router belong to ISP and I can't access/configure it. PC 1 is a linux box: eth0 and wlan0 are bridged (enslaved to br0 with address 192.168.1.2); hostapd is running on PC 1 sharing internet connection with PC WX. I want to redirect connections to some ports on PC 1 toward PCs on the same net, eg:

```
1.2.3.4:2222 > 192.168.1.2:2222 -> 192.168.1.3:22
1.2.3.4:3333 > 192.168.1.2:3333 -> 192.168.1.4:25
```

I tried using iptables and enabling ip_forward

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.3:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.2
```

and so on for others ports, but it didn't work. I discovered that redirections toward any other PC connected via WLAN worked fine. It seems that, using iptables PREROUTING rule in conjunction with a bridge, once a packet has entered the bridge from one side (eth0), it can only flow to the other side (wlan0), but can't go out throw the same input interface. The arrangement described above worked fine when the bridge is disabled, but I dont't want to use PC 1 as a router but as AP only.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The rules you've suggested should work with a minor adjustment. Though it's not documented in `iptables`' man page, you must specify the protocol as the first argument to match, as follows:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.3:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.3 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.2
```

Note that the second rule is not required since the first rule triggers `iptables` to take care of the responses automatically.

If it still doesn't work, try disabling iptables invocation while traversing the bridge via `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` and rebooting the machine.

Comment: Have you deleted the second rule? Can you please detail what exactly is not working? Is the first rule invoked? Do you have access from `192.168.1.2` to `192.168.1.3` and vice versa?

Comment: @PaoloRossi, what's the output of `route -n`?

Comment: route -n prints these lines:\n Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface\n
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 br0\n
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo\n
192.168.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0\n

Comment: @PaoloRossi, do you have ping from `192.168.1.2` to `192.168.1.3` or to `192.168.1.4`, and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, from 192.168.1.2 I can ping all PCs wired or wireless connected.

Comment: @PaoloRossi, is `etables` empty? Can you try disabling `iptables` invocation while traversing the bridge via `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` and rebooting your computer?